# What's the purpose of exit(0) ?

Tags: c, linux, exit

I understand that `exit(1)` indicated an error , for example :

```
if (something went wrong) 

     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

But what's the purpose of using `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);` ?

When handling with processes maybe ? e.g. for `fork()` ?

thanks

Comment: If you find out that your program has done everything it needed to do, and are not in `main()`, then you call `exit(0)`.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Then you mean that this is way to make my code to return to its invoking function , without using `return` ?

Comment: It's a way to end the execution of your program, almost immediately (some graceful shutdown routines may will be run if scheduled) with the specified exit code. If by "invoking function" you mean the shell or alike, then yes; if you mean some function in the same program, then no.

Comment: @DanielFischer: This should be an answer +1

Comment: Doesn't offer much if anything above the answer of chmeee with a bit of Levon's answer, so I don't think it's necessary to make it an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This gives the part of the system that invokes the program (usually the command shell) a way to check if the program terminated normally or not.

**Edit**   - start -

By the way, it is possible to query the exit code of an interactive command as well through the use of the `$?` shell variable. For instance this failed `ls` command yields an exit code of value `2`.

> ```
> $ ls -3
> ls: invalid option -- '3'
> Try `ls --help' for more information.
> $ echo $?
> 2
> ```

**Edit**  - end -

Imagine a batch file (or shell script) that invokes a series of programs and depending on the outcome of each run may choose some action or the other. This action may consist of a simple message to the user, or the invocation of some other program or set of programs.

This is a way for a program to return a status of its run.

*Also*, note that *zero* denotes no problem, any *non-zero* value indicates a problem.

Programs will often use different non-zero values to pass more information back (other than just non-normal termination). So the non-zero exit value then serves as a more specific error code that can identify a particular problem. This of course depends on the meanings of the code being available (usually/hopefully in the documentation)

For instance, the [ls man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls) has this bit of information at the bottom:

> Exit status is 0 if OK, 1 if minor problems, 2 if serious trouble.

For Unix/Linux man pages, look for the section titled EXIT STATUS to get this information.

Comment: 0 does indicate success, but a non-zero value might or might not indicate a problem. Per 1999 C 7.20.4.3 5, the meaning of any value other than 0, EXIT_SUCCESS, or EXIT_FAILURE is implementation-defined. For example, an implementation could use the low bits of the status to indicate success or failure and the high bits to convey additional information, such as how many widgets were processed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks .. that's useful information and good to know.

Comment: It also allows a human to determine if the program terminated normally or not. Just saying

Comment: @PerJohansson Yes, of course, you are right .. I'll add an explicit note regarding this .. plus the use of `$?`

Answer (score 1):

you can only exit your program from the main function by calling return. To exit the program from anywhere else, you can call exit(EXIT_SUCCESS). For example, when the user clicks an exit button.

Comment: well, you can also use `exit()` in `main`

Answer (score 1):

It's a system call. There's always good information on system calls if you check the man pages:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/exit

On a Linux box, you can simply type `man exit` into a terminal and this information will come up.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of 'normally' exiting a program: returning from `main()`, or calling `exit()`.  Normally `exit()` is used, and thought of, for signalling a failure.  However, if you are not in `main()`, you must still exit somehow.  `exit(0)` is usually used to terminate the process when not in `main()`.

`main()` is actually not a special function to the operating system, only to the runtime environment.  The 'function' that actually gets loaded is normally defined as `_start()` (this is handled by the linker, and beyond the scope of this answer), written in assembly, which simply prepares the environment and calls `main()`.  Upon return from `main()`, it also calls `exit()` with the return value from `main()`.